# cassandra driver: return set of failures in list of futures

Tags: java, asynchronous, cassandra, kotlin, future

I've got a list of futures that perform data deletion for given list of `studentId`s from cassandra:

```
val studentIds: List<String> = getStudentIds(...)
val boundStatements: List<BoundStatement> = studentIds.map(bindStudentDelete(it))
val deleteFutures = boundStatements.map { session.executeAsync(it) }
deleteFutures.forEach {
    // callback that will send metrics for monitoring
    Futures.addCallback(it, MyCallback(...))
}
```

Above I have registered a callback `MyCallback(...)` for each future for sending metrics. Then I do:

```
Futures.inCompletionOrder(deleteFutures).forEach { it.get() }
```

to wait for the completion of all the deletes. If for any reason that some of the futures end up failing (cancelled, something else goes wrong, etc.), I want to return the list of `studentId`s so that I can deal with it later.

What is the best way to achieve that?

**EDIT**
The callback could be a way to mutate a state to track success/failure of all the deletions.

```
class MyCallback(
    private val statsDClient: StatsdClient,
    private val tags: Array<String>,
    val failures: MutableList<String>
) : FutureCallback<Any> {
    override fun onSuccess(result: Any?) {
        //send success metrics
        ...
    }
    override fun onFailure(t: Throwable) {
        // send failure metrics
        ...
        // do something here to get the associated studentId
        val currId = ...
        failures.add(currId)
    }
}
```

Similarly, I could mutate a state in `Futures.inCompletionOrder(deleteFutures).forEach` block with a `try/catch`:

```
val failedDeletes = mutableListOf<String>()
Futures.inCompletionOrder(deleteFutures).forEach {
    try {
        it.get()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        // do something to get the studentId for this future
        val currId = ...
        failedDeletes.add(currId)
    }
}
```

However, there are 2 things I don't like/know about it. One is that it's mutating a state that we have to define outside. The other is that I still don't know how to get the `studentId` from the point of failure (in `onFailure` or `catch` block).

Comment: This really may depend on multiple factors - what version of cassandra you're using, number of requests that you're issuing, load to Cassandra servers, etc. - can you provide more details?

Comment: @AlexOtt here's my cassandra setting: `cqlsh 4.1.1 | Cassandra 2.0.17 | CQL spec 3.1.1 | Thrift protocol 19.39.0`. Not sure why # of requests & load has to do with this question though.

Answer (score 0):

I have added a code snippet below in JAVA. This is blocking procedure.

> ResultSet getUninterruptibly()
>
> Waits for the query to return and return its result. This method is
>   usually more convenient than Future.get() because it:
>   Waits for the result uninterruptibly, and so doesn't throw InterruptedException.
>   Returns meaningful exceptions, instead of having to deal with ExecutionException.
>   As such, it is the preferred way to get the future result.

Check this link:
[Interface ResultSetFuture](https://docs.datastax.com/en/drivers/java/2.0/com/datastax/driver/core/ResultSetFuture.html)

```
    List<ResultSetFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> futureStudentIds = new ArrayList<>();
    // List<Long> successfullIds = new ArrayList<>();
    List<Long> unsuccessfullIds = new ArrayList<>();

    for (long studentid : studentids) {
        futures.add(session.executeAsync(statement.deleteStudent(studentid)));
        futureStudentIds.add(studentid);
    }

    for (int index = 0; index < futures.size(); index++) {
        try {
            futures.get(index).getUninterruptibly();
            // successfullIds.add(futureStudentIds.get(index));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            unsuccessfullIds.add(futureStudentIds.get(index));
            LOGGER.error("", e);
        }
    }
    return unsuccessfullIds;
```

For Non-blocking you can use `ListenableFuture`.
[Asynchronous queries with the Java driver](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/java-driver-async-queries)